# Determine which of the following are subspaces of $\textbf{R}^{3}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the following subsets of $\textbf{R}^{3}$

$V_{6} = \{(x,y,z) \mid (x + 2y + 3z = 0)\wedge(x + y -z = 0)\}$

$V_{7} = \{(x,y,z) \mid (x + 2y + 3z = 0)\vee(x + y - z = 0)\}$.

Can someone explain why $V_{6}$ is a subspace but not $V_{7}$?

Comment: "or" between assertions means "union" of the corresponding sets : the union of two planes is neither a plane, nor a straight line, nor the origin, therefore isn't a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a given subset of a vector space to be a subspace, it is necessary that all the conditions of being a vector space apply. But most of them are simply inherited from the bigger subspace ($\mathbb{R}^3$, in this case). So usually we only need to show that the subset is closed for addition and scalar multiplication.

For $V_7$, since we only need one of the equations to be true for a vector, we can take a triplet $v_1 = (1,-1,0) \in V_7$ for it satisfies the second equation, and another $v_2 = (1,0,- 1/3) \in V_7$, since it satisfies the second equation. Then we have:
$$v_3 = v_1+v_2 = (2,-1,-1/3)$$
wich is such that
$$x_3 + 2y_3 + 3z_3 = 2 + 2\times(-1) + 3\times(-1/3) = 2-2-1 = -1$$
and
$$ x_3 + y_3 -z_3 = 2 - 1 - (-1/3) = 4/3 $$
Hence, the sum of those two vectors in $V_7$ doesn't lie on $V_7$ and therefore it is not a subspace.
For $V_6$ we can prove it's closure with respect to addition and scalar multiplication:

Suppose $v_1 = (x_1,y_1,z_1),v_2  = (x_2,y_2,z_2)\in V_6$, and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Then
$$v_3 = v_1+ v_2 = (x_1 + x_2, y_1 + y_2, z_1 + z_2) = (x_3, y_3, z_3)$$
is such that:
$$x_3 + 2y_3 + 3z_3 = (x_1+x_2) + 2(y_1+y_2) + 3(z_1+z_2) = $$
$$ x_1 + 2y_1 + 3z_1 + x_2 + 2y_2 + 3z_2 = 0 + 0 = 0 $$
and
$$x_3 + y_3 -z_3 = (x_1+x_2) + (y_1+y_2) - (z_1+z_2) = $$
$$x_1 + y_1 - z_1 + x_2 + y_2 - z_2 = 0 + 0 = 0$$
And for scalar multiplication we have

$$v_4 = \alpha v_1 = (\alpha x_1, \alpha y_1, \alpha z_1) $$
Now
$$ x_4 + 2y_4 + 3z_4 = \alpha x_1 + 2 \alpha y_1 +3 \alpha z_1 = \alpha(x_1 + 2y_1 + 3z_1) = 0$$
$$ x_4 + y_4 -z_4 = \alpha x_1 + \alpha y_1-\alpha z_1  = \alpha(x_1 + y_1 - z_1) = 0$$
And so $V_6$ is closed with respect to the vector operations. Therefore, a subspace.

In simpler terms, $V_6$ is the intersection of two other subspaces (two planes containing the origin) and $V_7$ is their union. And the intersection of subspaces is always a subspace, whereas for the union, this is not necessarily true.